# What's the best way for a web server to maintain a copy of a specific div in the client's DOM as it is manipulated by jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom, client, headless

I'm building a sort of html document editor with javascript and jquery.  I want the server to maintain the current state of the document.  The server side will be implemented in java or php.

On the client I have a palette of html elements which the user can add to the document. Everything that can be added is wrapped in a div. Inside the document the user will be manipulating the tree structure, grouping/wrapping elements in divs, and moving divs to be children of siblings.  Some divs will have forms in them, and I need the values in the forms to persist to the server too.

What do you think is the best way to do this without sending the whole document to the server every time a change occurs?

Comment: Well, you could have a 'save' button somewhere on the page allowing the user to save the file when they are ready, then maybe a `setTimeout` in the background auto-saving every couple minutes or what-have-you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you have three choices:

1. You can send the entire document to the server everytime it's changed or after a short pause of inactivity (e.g. 60 seconds of no activity) like an autosave.
2. You can create a skeleton description of the document that isn't the actual HTML and is a lot more compact, but still describes where all your predetermined widgets are located.  For example a particular pre-defined widget could be described as simple "A" rather than the already known HTML that makes it up.
3. You can send just each change to the server (e.g. move item 13 to be a child of item 19, or delete item 20) and maintain a duplicate structure on the server by applying each change as they happen.

If the data isn't large (e.g. under 100k) and it's easy to parse the whole data on your server, it's probably more trouble than it's worth to implement items 1 and 2.

I'd recommend implementing choice #1 and then see how it performs and only go to something more complicated if you have to.